# How to customize the Color Function Editor?

Tags: color, histograms, customization, interface, image3d

I'm happy with Mathematica's inbuilt Colour Function Editor. However, I wish to add some extra functionalities to this to make it customised for my purpose. For example,

1. I wish to manipulate the number of bins for the histogram plot.
2. By default, the number of keys should be equal to the number of peaks in the histogram and the key should be placed exactly at the peak points.
3. I also wish to have a provision to apply custom colour scheme as well.

Comment: @Kuba I had the same question. Google brought me to this: [Edit Color Function Palette for Image3D](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/3d-volumetric-image-processing/edit-color-function-palette-for-image3d.html). Apparently it is a tool to edit the color function used to represent a 3D dataset, like `Image3D`. I have never used it, nor did I know it existed :-)

Comment: ``Get["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions@Image`ColorFunctionEditor``

Comment: @Kuba: It's giving me a syntax error message:                                                             Syntax::tsntxi: "<<GeneralUtilities`\n PrintDefinitions@Image`ColorFunctionEditor" is incomplete; more input is needed.

Comment: Ad 2. Click on the plot while pressing `Alt`. Another locator will be created.

Answer (score 3):

There is a minor error in Kuba's comment. Try this

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions @ Image`ColorFunctionEditor;
```

You should get a window that looks like this

[image: window]

Within that Notebook the function names, e.g. `ColorFunctionEditorInline`, may be clicked to open an new Notebook with code for that function, and so on, to view more of the code behind this function.